# Tool to change a unit name and all references to it

Tags: delphi, pascal

If I make major changes to a unit I like to change its name to make it clear this is a different version and avoid confusion with other archived versions for example:
CSVUtils.PAS becomes CsvUtilsNew.PAS

But all references to it from other units have to be changed manually, eg:

```
Unit ManiForm

Uses
  CSVUtils
```

becomes

```
Unit ManiForm

Uses
  CsvUtilsNew
```

This gets very laborious in complex projects.

Icarus is very good at finding all the references, but I cant find any tool that would automatically update all the other units.

Does anyone know of any tools which automatically update unit references?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also define a unit alias in your project options.
E.g. `CSVUtils=CsvUtilsNew`

Comment: It certainly does work. I used this feature to help migrate from D6 to D2010. The units in question were Mike Lischke's XP theme manager units which got absorbed into Delphi in D7 and that led to name changes. Also the png and gif image units which had different names. I just needed the aliases whilst I wanted the code to compile with both compilers. And unit aliases worked superbly. I would not regard them as a long term solution though.

Comment: Unit aliases can be the right solution for component vendors who need a single source to compile in all delphi versions, but at the application level (not the vendor of component level) it stops making sense quickly.

Comment: We use List&Label as a report engine. It has the lovely feature of incorporating its version number in the unit names - there's `l17.pas`, `cmbtLL17.pas` and so on. We tackled this by an alias `cmbtLLAlias=cmbtLL17;LLAlias=l17` and putting the "...Alias" names into `uses` clauses.

Comment: These are all very useful tips, always amazing whats out there once you know what to look for !! I haven't accepted any of the 3 answers yet, as I suspect all 3 have their relative merits, so I didnt want to express favouritism where non-exists, I will try the methods suggested & see what works best for my application, Brian

Comment: This is a good trick CSVUtils=CsvUtilsNew which I didn't know about before, & which allows problems to be solved quickly, but I suspect is perhaps is best not used widespread, mostly because if others are working on the project they might not be aware of it & might cause confusion. Good debug quick-fix though?

Comment: LIst & Label is interesting, might be useful for certain scenarios where I currently would use t-chart or rave reports.

Answer (score 11):

I would use [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) Grep Search and Replace.

Comment: Any grep will work for this. I've used this (http://www.wingrep.com/) bare bones one for years.

Comment: Probably, but the GExperts grep is integrated into the IDE and somewhat tailored towards Delphi development.

Comment: @Ulrich, I agree. With GExperts grep you can i.e. limit your scope to projects, projects groups, directories etc.

Comment: useful tools, probably some other features in GExperts which I will also find useful, I like that its designed for Delphi.

Answer (score 8):

I would use Notepad++ or UltraEdit to Search&Replace in all files (*.pas, *.dpr, *.dproj) the old unit name with the new unit name. Unless you have variables or functions that have the same name as the unit, this works very well, is fast and does not require any specialized parser.